# Flutter Riverpod Error: Expression not evaluating to a function with `watch`

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

I'm migrating my Flutter project from GetX to Riverpod and encountered an error with using `watch` in Riverpod's `Consumer`. The error message is: "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked", specifically pointing to the usage of `watch`(countDownControllerProvider).state.isAnimating.

Here's the problematic code snippet:

```
child: Consumer(
  builder: (context, watch, child) {
    // Error occurs here
    final startPausedText = watch(countDownControllerProvider).state.isAnimating;
    // Rest of the code...
  },
);
```

Complete code context:

```
final countDownControllerProvider =
    StateProvider<CountDownController>((ref) => CountDownController());

class StartStopGroupButton extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const StartStopGroupButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<StartStopGroupButton> createState() =>
      _StartStopGroupButtonState();
}

class _StartStopGroupButtonState extends ConsumerState<StartStopGroupButton> {
  late final countDownController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    countDownController = ref.read(countDownControllerProvider);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
        child: Consumer(
          builder: (ref, watch, child) {
            final startPausedText =
                watch(countDownControllerProvider).state.isAnimating;

            return FloatingActionButton.extended(
              heroTag: 'btn1',
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: countDownController.startPaused,
              label: Text(
                startPausedText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this error occurs and how to resolve it using `watch` with Riverpod?

Thank you for any assistance or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builder: (ref, watch, child)` is not the proper parameters for a `Consumer`.  You want `(context, ref, child)`.  And then you'll call `ref.watch` to do what you're trying to do with just `watch`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed all the suggestions you provided, but I encountered an error with `.state`.  Specifically, the error occurs in the following lines of code: `(context, ref, child) {
    final startPausedText =
        ref.watch(countDownControllerProvider).state.isAnimating;` The error message states the following: `The getter 'state' isn't defined for the type 'CountDownController'. Try importing the library that defines 'state', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'state'.` What should I do to resolve this error?

Comment: What kind of provider is countDownControllerProvider? EDIT: Oh, StateProvider.  Stop using those! The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Based on your experience, what is the better method to address the logic in the above code? I tried using FutureProvider as follows:
`final countDownControllerProvider = FutureProvider<CountDownController>((ref) async {
  return CountDownController();
});`

Comment: And here:
`Consumer( builder: (context, ref, child) {  final startPausedText = ref.watch(countDownControllerProvider).when( data: (countDownController) => countDownController.startPausedText,   loading: () => 'Loading...',   error: (error, stackTrace) => 'Error',  );  return FloatingActionButton.extended(   heroTag: 'btn1',   elevation: 0,   backgroundColor: Colors.white,  onPressed: () {     ref.watch(countDownController).state.startPaused();    },
      label: Text(   startPausedText.toString(),   style: TextStyle(     color: Colors.black,     fontSize: 24.0,    ),    ),  );  },),`

Comment: However, I encountered the following error when I clicked on the button, even though the button is displaying "null" on it: `Another exception was thrown: Expected a value of type 'ProviderListenable<dynamic>', but got one of type 'AsyncLoading<CountDownController>'`  It would be wonderful if you could assist me with that problem as well. Thank you for your previous response.